# How to declare and initialize this array of structs in C when the length is not known till runtime?

Tags: c, struct, compilation

#### foo.c

```
#include "main.h"
unsigned char currentBar;
struct foo myFoo[getNumBars()];

void initMyFoo(void)
{
 currentBar=(getNumBars()-1);
 for(i=0; i<(sizeof(myFoo)/sizeof(myFoo[0])); i++)
 {
  myFoo[i].we = 1;
  myFoo[i].want = 0;
  myFoo[i].your = 0;
  myFoo[i].soul = 0;
 }
}
```

#### main.c

```
#include "foo.h"
unsigned char getNumBars()
{
 return getDipSwitchValues();
}
initMyFoo();
```

(struct foo is declared in foo.h.)

This code has to execute without hard coding a number for Bars, as the number of Bars will change according to whatever the user sets his DIP switches. Right now I'm not able to initialize myFoo; I get the error "constant expression expected in initializer." Do I have to initialize it like:

```
struct foo myFoo[];
```

and change it later? If so, how do I make myFoo[] the correct length? I obviously don't have a constant available that corresponds to the desired size. Do I need to dynamically allocate this or something?

I found this similar answer but it wasn't too helpful for me - [C++ a class with an array of structs, without knowing how large an array I need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474282/c-a-class-with-an-array-of-structs-without-knowing-how-large-an-array-i-need)

Answer (score 3):

```
struct foo* myFoo;
unsigned int myFooSize;

void initMyFoo(void)
{
  myFooSize = getNumBars();
  myFoo = malloc(myFooSize * sizeof(*myFoo));
  for (i=0; i<myFooSize; i++) {
    /* ... */
  }
}

void cleanupMyFoo(void)
{
  free(myFoo);
  myFoo = NULL;
  myFooSize = 0;
}
```

Comment: If he's using C, he doesn't need to cast the pointer back from `malloc` explicitly.

Comment: If `getNumBars()` is untrusted user input, you should test that the multiplication by `sizeof *myFoo` doesn't wrap around.

Answer (score 1):

1 - in C99 you can use [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), which allow you to create arrays whose lengths are runtime-determined. You can also use them via compiler extensions (GCC supports them for non-C99 C and C++), but that's not a portable solution.

```
int someUnknownSize = 0;

/* some code that changes someUnknownSize */

struct foo myFoo[someUnknownSize];
```

2 - Declare a pointer that will be allocated memory at runtime with `malloc` or `calloc`.

```
struct foo *fooPtr = 0; /* null pointer to struct foo */
int sizeToAlloc = 0;
/* determine how much to allocate/modify sizeToAlloc */
fooPtr = malloc(sizeToAlloc * sizeof(*fooPtr));

/* do stuff with the pointer - you can treat it like you would an array using [] notation */
free(fooPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually go for an expected maximum array size and if it's needed, just resize it:

```
type * a = calloc(sizeof(type),exp_array_size);
```

and upon pushing a new value onto the array (yeak, OK, I treat it as if it was a stack...), I check its current size against the new one:

```
if (current_size > max_size) {
    max_size *= 2;
    realloc(a,max_size*sizeof(type));
}
```